# Is there a mechanism to protect Stack Overflow against users with new account just to avoid downvoting?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, new-users

Is there a way to protect Stack Overflow from users that, for multiple reasons, will create a new account to post a question with laziness and expecting a 'copy-paste' solution?

Take this example: **a-good-question** from user####### scoring 1 reputation. The user posted a clear question: **clear-and-related-question-title**

If I have, for example, the following function:

```
void foo(constantA, constantB)
{
  ... code
    {
      //Do stuff
    }
  //Do other stuff
{
```

**mode-details-from-OP** to clarify situation.

Complementary information from the OP:

```
if (OP code)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

In my example, the user made a clear question, added his code and the question seems OK. Somehow, I suspect this user to know the Stack Overflow mechanism and decided to post his question under another account just to avoid being down-voted.

Are there any treads about this subject and are there ways to avoid considering some questions from **new users** like questions from **reputation freak scary users**?

How can we stop this behavior, if this behavior is happening, otherwise, is there a way to distinguish a good willing 'new user' from a 'I'm afraid to look stupid and scrap my reputation' user?

Comment: So you want to do some type of action against new users because they ask good questions?

Comment: I did not know we were punishing good behaviour now... well, off to downvote everything

Comment: is there a way to differ a good willing 'new user' from a 'i'm afraid to look stupid and scrap my reputation' user ?

Comment: Perhaps at the IP/system level. But then again, there is nothing forbidden about having multiple accounts. (As long as these accounts are not used for vote-fraud or to circumvent bans).

Comment: This is my guess about what you mean, please clarify me if I'm wrong: You think that some high-reputation users are creating new accounts to ask simple questions, because they are afraid of looking stupid? And you think that this is a problem?

Comment: @Bart - why is that?  What reason would you need for multiple accounts, other than hilariously chatting back and forth with each other?

Comment: @EmilVikström Thanks for clarifying for me, **YES** _this is my thought_.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables that is not enough of a reason for you? But jokes aside, I have absolutely no need for multiple accounts. It has however been stated time and time again that having multiple accounts is not necessarily seen as any violation, provided that they are not used as part of fraudulent behaviour. And simply asking questions is not fraudulent.

Comment: Damn, this question is killing my reputation, i should have asked it under a newUser account ! ;)

Comment: I bet at least 40% of the bad questions on the site are posted by Jon Skeet under thousands of false names.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your question (after the comment discussion), you think there are high-reputation users that are creating new accounts because they are afraid of asking simple questions with their main one.

First, I do not agree that this is a problem. We do not need to track down these users and force them to reveal themselves.

Second, smart people are not afraid of asking simple questions. In fact, asking questions is one of the est ways of learning. A potential recruiter, for example, looking into the question history of a job candidate will not back down just because some question seems easy, at least not a good recruiter. The important thing is often just the ability to learn, and asking questions is the foundation of learning (be it the actual asking, or just curiosity). If these users are hiding behind new account, which I doubt, we (as a human society, not necessarily Stack Overflow) need to make it comfortable for them to ask the questions out in the open.

Comment: I wonder if admins can take a look correlation between IP addresses and accounts in order to make a statistic ?

Comment: But why? There is no value in such statistics.

Comment: can you help me understand why this question got to -20 ? It feels like i was the only one thinking about this and i disturbed the whole community by asking it.

Comment: You can read under [Help -> What's meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) that voting here is different. Before August 2013 downvotes on all questions here just meant that people disagreed with the sentiment, not that your post was necessarily bad. Downvotes on feature-requests still mean that people don't want the feature.